# Find the longest word in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I'm trying to solve this task -
"given a string, return the word with the highest score. The score can be calculated the following way:

- for each vowel, add +1 to the score (["a", "e", "i", "o",
  "u", "y"])
- for each constant ["b", "d"] substract 1 from the score

for example, "butterfly" will have the score of 2, we add +3 for each vowel ("u","e","y") and substract 1 for constant ("b"). The word "day" will have score of 2 ( we add 2 for "a","y"). The function needs to return the word with the highest score.

This is my code so far:

```
function countVowels(string) {
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] 
  let constants = ["b", "d"]

  let words = string.trim().split(" ")

  let highestScore = " ";
  let count =0;
  
  for(const c of words){
    for (let i=0; i<c.length; i++){

        if(vowels.includes(c[i])) {
        highestScore = c
        count++;
        }
        else if (constants.includes(c[i])) count--    
    }
}
console.log(highestScore)
return highestScore;

}

countVowels("what a beautiful day")
```

The issue is that my code returns the last word in the sentence, not the word with the highest score. If I pass "what a beautiful day", function returns "day" not "beautiful". I can't seem to find a way to return the correct value. Any advise and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting the score (`count`) to individualize it to each word. You can use `Array#map` to do that as follows:

```js
function countVowels(string) {
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] 
  let constants = ["b", "d"]

  let words = string.trim().split(" ")
  
  const scores = words.map(word => {
      let score = 0;
      for (let i=0; i < word.length; i++){

        if(vowels.includes(word[i])) {
            score++
        }
        else if (constants.includes(word[i])) score--    
    }
    console.log( word, score ); //output each word and score 
    return [word, score];
  })
  .sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]); //sort the array in descending order of score
  return scores[0][0]; //return the WORD with highest score
}

console.log('Word with highest score: ' + countVowels("what a beautiful day") );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another variable to keep track of the score of *one* word you're iterating over, separate from the highest score found so far. More precise variable names will help some too - `highestScore` sounds like a number (a score), but your current code has it as a string. Consider using something like `bestWordFoundSoFar`.

```js
function countVowels(string) {
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  const constants = ["b", "d"]
  const words = string.trim().split(" ")

  let bestWordSoFar;
  let scoreOfBestWordSoFar = 0;;

  for (const word of words) {
    let thisWordScore = 0;
    for (const char of word) {
      if (vowels.includes(char)) thisWordScore++;
      else if (constants.includes(char)) thisWordScore--
    }
    if (thisWordScore > scoreOfBestWordSoFar) {
      bestWordSoFar = word;
      scoreOfBestWordSoFar = thisWordScore
    }
  }
  return bestWordSoFar;
}

console.log(countVowels("what a beautiful day"));
```

A somewhat more functional approach can be had with `.reduce`, to keep track of and return the best word found.

```js
function countVowels(string) {
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const constants = ["b", "d"];
  const getWordScore = (word) => {
    let thisWordScore = 0;
    for (const char of word) {
      if (vowels.includes(char)) thisWordScore++;
      else if (constants.includes(char)) thisWordScore--
    }
    return thisWordScore;
  };
  return string
    .trim()
    .split(" ")
    .reduce((bestWordSoFar, word) => getWordScore(word) > getWordScore(bestWordSoFar) ? word : bestWordSoFar);
}

console.log(countVowels("what a beautiful day"));
```